# Unable to place div on other div

Tags: css

Let me explain what I'm trying to achieve. Currently, I have button and want to add image and add text. I have parent div container in which all child div adds dynamically.

Add image button adds img tag with image inside the parent div and add text button adds div containing text inside parent by using append method.

But what I want that when ever I create them, they should place in a specific position which will be common to all. Lets take center of the parent so when ever I add image or text it should create at the center of the parent

Code for adding dynamic image

```
  $(document).ready(function () { 
        $('#addImage').click(function () { 
            var url = 'Default.aspx'; 
            var dialog = $('<iframe"></iframe>').appendTo('body'); 
            dialog.load(url).dialog('open').dialog({ modal: true, width: 480,resizable: false ,open: function (type, data) { $(this).parent().appendTo("form"); },
            buttons: {
        'OK': function() {

        var img = document.createElement('img');
           $(img).attr("id", "dyndiv" + count);
           $(img).attr("width", 60);
           $(img).attr("height", 140);
           $(img).attr("src", 'Uploads/'+ $get('dvFileName').innerHTML) ;
           var $ctrl = $(img).addClass("draggable ui-widget-content").draggable({ containment: '#containment-wrapper', cursor: 'move', snap: '#containment-wrapper' });
           objid = "dyndiv" + count ;
           count++;

            $("#containment-wrapper").append($ctrl);
           $(this).dialog('destroy');
          },
        'Cancel': function() {
            $(this).dialog('destroy');
            // I'm sorry, I changed my mind                 
        }
    }                
             }); 

            return false; 

        }); 
    });
```

Comment: Show us your code, and let your code speak for itself.

Comment: what i want that if i place 2 images they should create on the same position.

Answer (score 1):

At last i got the solution. In the above question I am appending the div, now i am also explicitly defining the position of the div after the append statement above.